# How to store cart in user defined table using Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart in laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to store a cart in database in user defined table.
But when I call save(); method in controller, It gives me error like!

### Call to undefined method Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::store()

Here is the function of my controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
  $this->validate($request, [
    'guest_name' => 'required|max:255',
    'guest_phone' => 'required',
    'guest_email' => 'required',
    'guest_address' => 'required',
  ]);
    $guest = new Guest;
    $guest->name = $request->guest_name;
    $guest->phone = $request->guest_phone;
    $guest->email = $request->guest_email;
    $guest->address = $request->guest_address;
    $guest->payment_method = $request->payment_method;
    $guest->save();

    $cart = new Cart;
    $cartDetails = Cart::content();
    $subtotal = Cart::subtotal();
    foreach($cartDetails as $c){
      $cart->guest_id = $guest->id;
      $cart->products = $c->name;
      $cart->qty = $c->qty;
      $cart->price = $c->price;
      $cart->subtotal = $c->subtotal;
      $cart->save();
    }

    return view('guest/track')->with('msg','Your Order has been placed! You\'ll get an email shortly!');
  //$find = DB::table('guests')->where('id',$guest->id)->first();
}
```

Comment: I know I can store it by using its own store('username') command but it looks pretty bad!
In content it gives the product names in messy looks... And I can not retrieve data in a good manner so I just created my own table and tried inserting the data into the table. 
But it is not storing the data. 
Please help!!!

Comment: Have you installed the package properly? i.e. Registered the service provider, and added the alias to you aliases array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable problem is you have 2 conflicting class names of `Cart`, one is most probably the package and the other being your model.

You can get around this by the following:

When including your model like the following:

```
use models\Cart;
```

Change this to something like:

```
use models\Cart as CartModel;
```

Comment: Not a problem at all!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you followed the steps given at [here](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart). Check your `config/app.php` > providers array for below line:

```
Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\ShoppingcartServiceProvider::class
```

If it not there then place it and check. May be this is the reason for this exception.

Comment: The package is accurately installed... I've just double checked it!

Answer (score 0):

using the package shoppingcart table, to overcome the messy look, to retrieve data in a good manner you can catch shoppingcart table in your controller like:

```
public function dbcart(){
    $cc=DB::table('shoppingcart')
        ->get();
    return view('dbcart',compact('cc'));
}
```

and then in your view dbcart.blade.php first unserialize the content and then iterate over it:

```
@extends('cmaster')
@section('content')
@foreach($cc as $item)

    <?php $pp=unserialize($item->content) ?>

    @foreach ($pp as $it)
        {{$it->name}}<br/>
        {{$it->qty}}<br/>

    @endforeach
@endforeach
@endsection
```